# Strange js object's field behaviour in Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to reassign targetRow's field with variable converted from `String` to `Number`, but Chrome's console gives me some strange output:

```
  targetRow[fieldName] = Number(value);
  console.log(targetRow[fieldName]);                  // => 12
  console.log(targetRow[fieldName]===Number(value));  // => true
  console.log(targetRow);
```

[image]

When this object is passed to the state, it behaves as like field's value is `undefined`.

```
let execPlanTmp = this.state.execPlan.slice();
execPlanTmp[rowIdx] = targetRow;
this.setState({execPlan: execPlanTmp});
console.log(this.state.execPlan);
```

[image]

**Upd:**
   `JSON.stringify(targetRow)` returns the correct string, which is passed to the server, but js object's field is still treated as undefined by React and Chrome.

**Upd 2**
This is the whole function:

```
onCellEdit = (row, fieldName, value) => {
    let rowId = this.state.execPlan.indexOf(row);

    if (rowId >= 0) {
        let execPlanTmp = this.state.execPlan.slice();
        execPlanTmp[rowId][fieldName] = Number(value);
        this.setState({execPlan: execPlanTmp});

        fetch("http://localhost:8080/api", {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(execPlanTmp[rowId]),
            mode: "cors"
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Is `fieldName === 'expectedExecTotal'`?

Comment: yes, it has the same value

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue once. It is because when you do `console.log(someVar)` it does not literally mean "make text from someVar and print it", it shows you the value that is stored in the memory by the moment you click collapsed (`{...}`) array, so if the value has changed before you click but after `console.log()` it changes in console.

Run next code in the console and you will understand:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    arr.push({a: i, b: 0});
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr).substr(0, 700));
for (var j in arr){
  arr[j].b=Math.random();
}
```

Output:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQsvs.png)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but still i can't understand why object's field becomes `undefined`.

Comment: Can you show full code? Maybe `expectedExecTotal` changes after you console.log it? Maybe your callback (or function) runs twice?